# history.go(-1) not loading my other function

Tags: javascript, html

i have function resizeIframe at my page, then after clicking next the iframe resize at a bigger height but when i go back using history.go my iframe still in bigger height. why is it the function resizeiframe does not load again?

This is the code of for resizing the iframe:

```
function resizeIframe()

{
  {
document.getElementById('content').style.height = 70;
    }
    ;
    {
      document.getElementById('content').style.height = document.getElementById('content').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
```

}

it is being called on iframe onload.

Comment: You'll have to show us the code being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.referrer to go back with page refresh

```
window.location.href = document.referrer;
// For IE
if(IE){ //IE, bool var, has to be defined
    var newlocation = document.createElement('a');
    newlocation.href = URLtoCall;
    document.body.appendChild(newlocation);
    newlocation.click();
}
```